# where did my google play app go?

Tags: android, google-play

Last night I released a google play app and this morning it was in the play store and had even received a review.

Right now I checked and it isn't there anymore but it still says published.

Could it have been removed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third-party service, and is not a software engineering related.

Comment: @user3130086 In regards to your last comment, that kind of behavior will not be tolerated here and I strongly advise against continuing to act like this in the future. Additionally, this question is off topic for Stack Overflow. You can find more information on what kind of questions are on topic in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time i published an application, i couldnt see it in searchs for 1 week. Everything is possible with google play actually. But if they removed your application, u supposed to have a mail from them for sure. If u didnt, probably its a temporary problem. Wait today and if it wont be fixed, send a mail to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go on this url using your application package:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=HERE_GOES_YOUR_PACKAGE

If it is there, you just have to wait for google to index it, sometimes it takes a couple of days.

You can also try this, that lists all your applications, this needs even more time then the app to get updated:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=HERE_GOES_YOUR_PUBLISHER_NAME_ESCAPED_URL

Example for my app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.cpiacente.fticker

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Cristian+Piacente